# Why does my Keras CNN always guess one number? Why is my Loss so high?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Ive been working on this CNN. In the `Test()` function it always says that it is 1 given number. (example. always outputting 8 even though it's not even close). Ive tried training the model more to see if the model was just not good enough. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
(Train_Data, Train_Labels), (Test_Data, Test_Labels) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()


Train_Data = Train_Data.reshape(60000,28,28,1)
Test_Data = Test_Data.reshape(10000,28,28,1)
Train_Data = Train_Data / 255 - 0.5
Test_Data = Test_Data / 255 - 0.5

def load(name):
    net = keras.models.load_model(name)
    return net
def save(name):
    model.save(name)
    print("""

###:::SAVING MODEL:::###

    """)
def makeCNN():
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(9, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimzer='adam', loss="mse", metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
def train(epochs):
    for i in range(epochs):
        print(i+1)
        model.fit(Train_Data, Train_Labels)
        save('CNN.h5')




def test():
    validCorrect = 0
    validTotal = 0
    print(Test_Data.shape)
    for i in range(1000):
        data = Test_Data[i]
        data = data.reshape(1,28,28,1)
        prediction = model.predict(data)
        validTotal +=1

        if np.argmax(prediction) == Test_Labels[i]:
            validCorrect+=1

            print(f"""
            TOTAL:{validTotal}
            ACCURACY:{(validCorrect/validTotal)*100}
            CORRECT:{validCorrect}
            """)
        print(f"GUESS:{np.argmax(prediction)}
        REALITY{Test_Labels[i]}")







model = makeCNN()

train(80)
test()
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks! Im pretty new to Machine Learning(especially CNNs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should use `categorical_crossentropy` as your loss. It's tempting to use MSE, we're dealing with digits after all, but since this is a classification task, the model doesn't *know* about the supposed ordinality of the different digits. It just knows them as "ten different classes of image". For example, is a 7 more similar to a 2 or an 8? In terms of ordinality, it's closer to 8. But the digit looks rather more like a 2, doesn't it?

Also, I'm guessing that your model is likely to under-fit quite severely, because is not deep enough. You can try adding some more convolutional layers to your network. You could draw inspiration from this example in the Keras documentation (also on the MNIST dataset) here https://keras.io/examples/mnist_cnn/ where they achieve >99% on this problem with just a couple of extra convolutional layers, and some techniques to reduce overfitting, such as dropout.

Comment: Impossible to say without further information. Maybe try copying and pasting the code from the documentation example and modifying from there.